# How to refresh a Fragment when popBackStackImmediate() is called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have log in button in shopping cart fragment. When this button is clicked, it redirects to sign in fragment. Also I have a button to login in sign in fragment. When this button is clicked, `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();` method is called. I want to refresh my shopping cart fragment on this method call.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing fragment you can override setUserVisibleHint method into your fragment. Whenever your fragment is visible on screen this refreshData method is call.

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
          RefreshData() ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the shopping cart `Fragment` when it becomes visible again by overriding `ShoppingCartFragment.onStart()`. See the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) of `Fragments`.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   @Override
   public void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      updateUi()
   }
}
```

You can enforce that the `ShoppingCartFragment` is recreated when the back stack is popped by using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` when showing the `LoginFragment`.

Comment: onStart method is not calling when fragment is called by getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();.

Comment: Ah I understand, your are adding the `LoginFragment`. Instead, replace the `ShoppingCartFragment` with the `LoginFragment`.

Comment: Yes I can, and you can too! ;)

Comment: In FragmentActivity Class use this method  public void closeCurrentFragment() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        for (int entry = 0; entry < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
  if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName().equalsIgnoreCase("shopping_checkout"));
            {
               
                addShoppingCheckoutFragment(getUserIdFromPrefs());
            }
        }

    }